Rotating text along the z axis
I am trying to plot this diagram and I want to place text in each of the cells in the grids so that the orientation is the same as the grid. Is this possible?

Here is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgftransformcm{1}{0.5}{0}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
    
    \draw[black, line width=1.5pt, fill=gray!10] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw[step=0.5cm,black!20] (0,0) grid (4,4);

    \node[align=center] at (2,1) {\rotatebox{90}{Rotated Text}};
    
    
    \draw[blue, line width=1.5pt, fill=blue!5] (4.5,-1) rectangle (6,0.5);
    \draw[step=0.5cm,blue!20] (4.4999,-1) grid (6,0.5);

    \draw[black, dotted, line width=1.5pt, fill=gray!10] (6.5,-5) rectangle (10.5,-1);
    \draw[step=0.5cm,black!20] (6.5, -5) grid (10.5,-1);
    \draw[black, dotted, line width=1.5pt,] (6.5,-2.5) rectangle (8,-1);
    \draw[-, thick] (1.5, 4) -- (8, -1);
    \draw[-, thick] (0, 2.5) -- (6.5, -2.5);
    
    \draw[red, line width=1.5pt,] (7,-2) rectangle (7.5,-1.5);
    \draw[red, line width=1.5pt,] (0.5,3) rectangle (1,3.5);
    \draw[red, line width=1.5pt,] (5,-0.5) rectangle (5.5,0);

    \draw[-, red] (1, 3) -- (7.5, -2);
    \draw[-, red] (0.5, 3) -- (7, -2);
    \fill[red, opacity=0.1] (1,3) -- (7.5,-2) -- (7,-2) -- (0.5,3) -- cycle;

    \draw[-, red] (1, 3) -- (7.5, -2);
    \draw[-, red] (1, 3.5) -- (7.5, -1.5);
    \fill[red, opacity=0.1] (1,3) -- (7.5,-2) -- (7.5,-1.5) -- (1,3.5) -- cycle;

    \draw[-, red] (0.5, 3) -- (7, -2);
    \draw[-, red] (0.5, 3.5) -- (7, -1.5);
    \fill[red, opacity=0.1] (0.5,3) -- (7,-2) -- (7,-1.5) -- (0.5,3.5) -- cycle;

    \draw[-, red] (0.5, 3.5) -- (7, -1.5);
    \draw[-, red] (1, 3.5) -- (7.5, -1.5);
    \fill[red, opacity=0.1] (0.5,3.5) -- (7,-1.5) -- (7.5,-1.5) -- (1,3.5) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{temp caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


feels like a job for \node[transform shape]

If i get your question right, maybe something like

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgftransformcm{1}{0.5}{0}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
    
    \draw[black, line width=1.5pt, fill=gray!10] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw[step=0.5cm,black!20] (0,0) grid (4,4);
    
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7}{
        \foreach \y in {0,...,7}
        {
            \node[transform shape, rotate = 90, font=\tiny] at (\x*0.5+0.25,\y*0.5+0.25) {Text};
        }
    }    
    
    \draw[blue, line width=1.5pt, fill=blue!5] (4.5,-1) rectangle (6,0.5);
    \draw[step=0.5cm,blue!20] (4.4999,-1) grid (6,0.5);
    

    \draw[black, dotted, line width=1.5pt, fill=gray!10] (6.5,-5) rectangle (10.5,-1);
    \draw[step=0.5cm,black!20] (6.5, -5) grid (10.5,-1);
    \draw[black, dotted, line width=1.5pt,] (6.5,-2.5) rectangle (8,-1);
    \draw[-, thick] (1.5, 4) -- (8, -1);
    \draw[-, thick] (0, 2.5) -- (6.5, -2.5);
    
    \draw[red, line width=1.5pt,] (7,-2) rectangle (7.5,-1.5);
    \draw[red, line width=1.5pt,] (0.5,3) rectangle (1,3.5);
    \draw[red, line width=1.5pt,] (5,-0.5) rectangle (5.5,0);

    \draw[-, red] (1, 3) -- (7.5, -2);
    \draw[-, red] (0.5, 3) -- (7, -2);
    \fill[red, opacity=0.1] (1,3) -- (7.5,-2) -- (7,-2) -- (0.5,3) -- cycle;

    \draw[-, red] (1, 3) -- (7.5, -2);
    \draw[-, red] (1, 3.5) -- (7.5, -1.5);
    \fill[red, opacity=0.1] (1,3) -- (7.5,-2) -- (7.5,-1.5) -- (1,3.5) -- cycle;

    \draw[-, red] (0.5, 3) -- (7, -2);
    \draw[-, red] (0.5, 3.5) -- (7, -1.5);
    \fill[red, opacity=0.1] (0.5,3) -- (7,-2) -- (7,-1.5) -- (0.5,3.5) -- cycle;

    \draw[-, red] (0.5, 3.5) -- (7, -1.5);
    \draw[-, red] (1, 3.5) -- (7.5, -1.5);
    \fill[red, opacity=0.1] (0.5,3.5) -- (7,-1.5) -- (7.5,-1.5) -- (1,3.5) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{temp caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


That works great. So does "transform shape" enable the node to follow the transformation that was applied to the image?

@Tatzz take a look @tikzmanual
